# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions

Tags: java, android

First of all, I tried almost all answers on *StackOverflow* to try this problem..!! But nothing works. I am sharing my program. Please have a look and let me know how to solve this issue.

Previously I was using **getFragmentManger()** method, but it throw the same exception. Then I tried this **getChildFragmentManager()** method. But Still it shows me the same exception..!!

**This is the code:**

```
public class FragmentC extends Fragment {

 private final List<String> mListGroup = new ArrayList<String>();
 private ViewPager viewPager;
 private ListPagerAdapter groupsPagesAdapter;
 private PagerTabStrip pagerTabs;
 public FragmentC() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        viewPager = (ViewPager) ((Activity)  parentContext).findViewById(R.id.pager);


    groupsPagesAdapter = new ListPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), viewPager); // Here I made the change, But still fails 


    pagerTabs = (PagerTabStrip) ((Activity) parentContext).findViewById(R.id.tabstrip);
    pagerTabs.setTabIndicatorColorResource(R.color.vert_manu);
    pagerTabs.setNonPrimaryAlpha(PAGER_TAB_SECONDARY_ALPHA);

    mListGroup.add(getString(R.string.contact_list_all_contact));
    mListGroup.add(getString(R.string.contact_list_no_group));
    groupsPagesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.contactlist, container, false);

    return v;
}

private class ListPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {


public ListPagerAdapter(final FragmentManager fm, final ViewPager viewPager) {
    super(fm);
    viewPager.setAdapter(this);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    String group = mListGroup.get(position);
    ContactListFragment f = ContactListFragment.newInstance(group);
    f.setListAdapter(getContactListAdapter(group));
    return f;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mListGroup.size();
}

@Override
public String getPageTitle(int position) {
    return mListGroup.get(position);
}

}
}
```